# Closing grandparent form from the grandchild

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to close the grandparent browser (from third party server) after the grandchild(from my side) is loaded. Below briefly describe how's the flow going:

After post.aspx is submitted, a new browser will be opened and this will navigate to the third party's page (TP1 page). After submitting it (TP1 page), it will open another browser (TP2 page). Submitting in TP2 will route back to my side's page receive.aspx.

> post.aspx (my side) --> open TP1 (not my side) --> open TP2 (not my
>   side) --> load to receive.aspx (my side)

From what I understand, TP1 will be grandparent form, and TP2 will be parent form of receive.aspx

Since TP1 and TP2 is not controllable from my side, is that possible to close TP1 after receive.aspx is loaded?

I have tried javascript

> window.parent.close()

at receive.aspx once it is loaded but it will only close TP2 but not TP1.

Comment: try window.parent.parent.close() before window.parent.close()

Comment: yes, i have tried it as well as window.top.parent.close(), it is not working :(

Comment: try `window.opener.opener.close()`?